# Cordova iOS notifications with phonegap-plugin-push and Firebase. No work

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, firebase-cloud-messaging, phonegap-plugins

I've created a cordova project with Visual Studio Code. I'm using this plugin: 
[phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) and I've follow the instructions.

I need to use notifications. I'm using Firebase and I've downloaded google-services.json, put it in my root, ran on Android and tested from Firebase cloud messaging. Everything works.

The problem: iOS. I've downloaded GoogleService-Info.plist, put on my root project and root platform ios.
Downloaded the p8 certificates from apple developer console and put on Firebase console:

[image]

So, when I launch this on index.js, ondeviceready:

```
onDeviceReady: function() {
    this.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    //alert("ciao");

    app.push = PushNotification.init({
        "android": {
            "senderID": "xxxx"
        },
        "ios": {
          "senderID": "xxxx",
          "sound": true,
          "vibration": true,
          "badge": true
        },
        "windows": {}
    });

    app.push.on('registration', function(data) {
        alert(data.registrationId);
        console.log("registration event: " + data.registrationId);
        document.getElementById("regId").innerHTML = data.registrationId;
        var oldRegId = localStorage.getItem('registrationId');
        if (oldRegId !== data.registrationId) {
            // Save new registration ID
            localStorage.setItem('registrationId', data.registrationId);
            // Post registrationId to your app server as the value has changed
        }
    });

    app.push.on('notification', function(data) {
        console.log('notification event');
        alert("qualcosa ricevuto: " + data.message + data.title);
    });

    app.push.on('error', function(e) {
        //console.log("push error = " + e.message);
        alert("push error = " + e.message);
    });
}
```

I receive the token on my iOS device (iPad & iPhone), but when I try to test it from Firebase, I can't see my devices registered token.
Why? What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Did you solve this issue? Pushnotification is undefined for me. Please post your solution.

Comment: No still not works, I’ve changed with native programming

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using the latest version of cordova-plugin-push (v2.2.3)?

Did you include the following in Cordova's config.xml?

```
<platform name="ios">
    <resource-file src="GoogleService-Info.plist" />
</platform>
```

Failing this please check the value of `data.registrationType` in your `.on('registration')` callback. The value should be `FCM`. If it's returning `APNS` then the registrationId will be a raw APNs token, not a Firebase token, in which case something in your configuration is amiss.